# How do I select distinct from a dataframe in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in R. I want to see what groups are in the dataframe. If this were a SQL database, I would do `Select distinct group from dataframe`. Is there a way to perform a similar operation in R?

```
> head(orl.df)
     long      lat order  hole piece group id
1 3710959 565672.3     1 FALSE     1   0.1  0
2 3710579 566171.1     2 FALSE     1   0.1  0
```

Comment: You can use sql as well. Take a look at the `sqldf` package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `unique()` function should do the trick:

```
> dat <- data.frame(x=c(1,1,2),y=c(1,1,3))
> dat <- data.frame(x=c(1,1,2),y=c(1,1,3))
> dat
  x y
1 1 1
2 1 1
3 2 3
> unique(dat)
  x y
1 1 1
3 2 3
```

Edit: For your example (didn't see the group part)

```
unique(orl.df$group)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the table() function is also a good choice.

```
table(orl.df$group)
```

It also tell you the number the items in each group.